# Linking `[foo]` results in []'s being incorrectly escaped

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks

Well, as the title says, I guess:

1. Start off with `[foo]`.
2. Use either the keyboard shortcut or editor button to wrap the `[foo]` in a hyperlink.
3. ... will result in [`\[foo\]`](http://google.com) rather than [`[foo]`](http://google.com)

---

This is due to the system blinding/ naively escaping all `[]`'s within the link, without checking whether it is contained with a code block or not.

Weirdly however, the syntax:
[[foo]](http://google.com) (i.e. `[[foo]][1]`) seems to work regardless, so I'm not sure this escaping of `[]` is even necessary?

This rendering bug happens both within the preview window, and within the actual post when submitted.

Comment: Eugh... I searched. I promise.

Comment: Not a problem, I just happened to remember Thiefmaster posting this recently.